# How to restore data on a non-unique key based on unique parent table key?

Tags: sql

I have a restored table of rows, `restoredData` that has partial information about `beer` and `cases`.  It contains a truncated version of the barcode of the `beer`, and full barcodes of the `case` per row.

All of `beers`, `beers_archive`, `cases`, `cases_archive`, are all missing some data due to a faulty stored procedure responsible for transferring items from `beers` to `beers_archive` and the same for cases.  I am responsible for restoring the missing items from `restoredData`, which has was created from text backups created every day.

I am trying to use this to restore some data to an `beer_archive` table I already have in existence.

Here's the issue, with my `cases` information from my restored table, which I already restored to `cases_archive`, I was able to just look at which full barcodes I had in my `restoredData` table that were not present in the `cases` or `cases_archive` table by unioning `cases` with `case_archive`, joining that on the `restoredData` and looking where the join `IS NULL`.  That told me what barcodes were present in `restoredData` that were not in the database, and I was able to insert them.

However, given that my beer shortened barcode is not unique, I cannot simply do as I did before.   It's possible that I have a beer barcode in my `restoredData` that already exists in either `beer` or `beer_archive`, but they could have two different parent `cases` which would indicate they're actually two different bottles.

One other piece of information - the `cases` do have a size column that indicates how many bottles there are per case - I was thinking somehow using that to see where the case size is say 6, but there's only 4 existing in `bottles` and `bottles_archive` which from there I could just look up the 2 in my restored data based on the case barcode.  Make a list of the cases that are have less bottles connecting to them than their count, and then going from there somehow.

My other thought was take my `restoredData`, which has every bottle and case ever made, and subtracting from it all the records that have a `beer.barcode` and `cases.fullBarcode` matching - leaving me only the rows with bottles that have a case barcode, but aren't present in `beer` or `beer_archive`.  However, I do not know how to write this in code.

Tables relevant columns look like so look like so

```
restoredData
beerBarcode    ....      caseFullBarcode


beers and beers_archive
beerBarcode ....     parentCaseId

cases and cases_archive
id ... casesFullBarcode ... caseSize
```

I personally think somehow just subtracting the bottles from the restored data that already exist based on the where query is the easiest way, but I also just thought it is possible that a case has two shortened beer barcodes that are identical which would still get missed then.

Any thoughts on how to tackle this?

UPDATE:

I have been able to get a list of all the ID's of all the cases that have a missing bottle.  I counted how many bottles join per case, compared it to the size of the case, and ordered by that subtraction.  At most cases are missing 1 bottle record.  However, from this list of ID's, it still seems unclear how to proceed.

UPDATE 2: I've given up trying to solve this only in SQL.  I am taking the query that generates the cases that are missing bottles and how many, and going from there to python to work on it.